# Does appearence of $\hbar$ implies the role of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I'm currently confused with the uncertainty in statistical mechanics and in quantum mechanics. As I understand, If roll a die, then you can get an outcome from the sample space
$$\mathcal{S}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$
There is uncertainty in the outcome, as we don't know the exact dynamics (which can be worked out in principle) of the rolling of the die. On the other hand, In quantum mechanics, We have an inbuilt uncertainty due to the uncertainty principle (a consequence of non-commutativity of two operators).

The two uncertainty are different in nature. The one in the statistical mechanics, According to my Prof., is due to a large number that is out inability to track large numbers. As we are not Maxwell's demon.

But I have seen, that whenever $\hbar$ (the reduced Planck's constant) appears in the expressions, some quantum things going on. And there are places in statistical mechanics where it does appear. I wanted to know

$$\text{Does the appearance of $\hbar$ in the expression always implies the quantum phenomena?}$$

Comment: Maybe make this question more specific by talking about the example where you have seen $\hbar$ appear?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of looking at it.

You are right that whenever h-bar pops up, quantum effects need to be taken into account. If h-bar were a larger number, then we could see strange quantum effects with our own eyes- and in the limit of h-bar going to zero, quantum effects vanish.

(As an aside, in the limit of the speed of light becoming infinite, relativity effects vanish too. And if the speed of light were a smaller number, then weird relativistic effects would appear not just in particle accelerators but also as you drive down the road in your car.)

Comment: About your aside: we have that in Minkowski spacetime there is an inherent maximum speed. Light and gravitational waves propagate at that maxiumum speed. The way you phrased it gives the appearance that you are referring to a property of *light*, rather than to a property of *Minkowski spacetime*. I take it you wrote it that way for brevity, but I believe the distinction matters. I find it an omission of physics language that there is no short name for it. For instance, *minkowski speed* would give it its own name.

Comment: @Cleonis, If you wish to write your own answer to this question, I will delete mine. Best regards, Niels

Answer (score 1):

Although $\hbar$ appears in classical statistical mechanics, it is only used to provide an absolute scale for entropy.  Since only differences in entropy matter, there is nowhere in classical stat mech where a prediction depends on the value of $\hbar$.  If we knew nothing about QM, there would just be "a constant with dimensions of action".

Comment: I don't think so, In statistical mechanics when you see $\hbar $, that means that reflects the quantum uncertainty.