# I can't track too many particle ==> Statistical Mechanics OR Quantum uncertainity ==> Statistical Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm sort of confused with these two ideas. We start by saying that the trajectory of the particle can be described by giving the phase space coordinate $(q,p)$. So Given the initial condition, I can tell where the particle will be in the future. That's sounds good. Next, we say, As we increase the number of particles in the system it's hard to track down these phase-space points. And thus We use the concept of probability......

Wikipedia says,

*In physics, statistical mechanics is a mathematical framework that applies statistical methods and probability theory to large assemblies of microscopic entities. It does not assume or postulate any natural laws but explains the macroscopic behavior of nature from the behavior of such ensembles.*

So this gives the feeling that probability theory is included because there is a large number of particles in the system.

---

Earlier I asked this question,

[Does the appearance of $\hbar$ imply the role of quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/617411/247238)

Further, We use the fact that it's not possible to specify the phase space point but a volume that is $h^3$ which comes from the uncertainty principle. There many $h$ that appear in classical statistical mechanics. And so I should conclude that quantum mechanics play a role here.

---

One thing I haven't clear is, The probability things that we have included here, Is it due to a large number of particles or due to the quantum uncertainty principle?

The uncertainty that we are tackling here, Is it inbuilt or due to a large numbers?

Comment: "The uncertainty that we are tackling here" --> What do you mean by "here" ? Quantum mechanics is the most fundamental theory we have to describe the behavior of small objects, and this requires probability. Statistical mechanics includes the uncertainty principle if applied to quantum (ie real) objects, but it *also* includes uncertainty due to a lack of knowledge of every particle's state; in other words we introduce statistical uncertainty by coarse-graining over the states of individual particles. This latter uncertainty is *often* (but not always) the dominant one in stat mech.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusing two issues.  Statistical mechanics replaces the momentum of lots of classical particles *i.e.* a long list of - say - $p_x$ values for each particle each moving along its own trajectory, by a few average quantities, such as the average momentum, and the statistical spread of the momentum values about the mean.  In this way instead of dealing with a list of $10^{25}$ numbers, you deal with $2$ ($\langle p_x\rangle$ and $\sigma_{p_x}$) while maintaining your ability to predict significant features of the system.

This had nothing to do with quantum-based uncertainty on some quantity, which remains even if there is a single particle and is an intrinsic feature of the theory.  If you prepare a *single* particle in a spin-up state along $=\hat z$, you cannot predict with certainly the outcome of a measurement of spin along $\hat y$.  Indeed if you prepared a second particle in exactly the same way, and performed the exact same experiment, the result could be vastly different even if you had perfect control of the experimental conditions.

In quantum mechanics we speak of averages in the sense that, by repeating the same experiment in precisely the same ideal conditions (possibly on a single-particle system) numerous times, we can get probabilities and averages of outcomes, not as a way of paring down on the overload of available information contained in a system with large number of constituents.

Comment: When we write the partition function of an ideal gas, we see that the $h$ appears in the expression, Is it signifies the role of quantum effect?

Comment: there's nothing to prevent you from doing quantum statistical mechanics, i.e. looking at very many quantum particles instead of very many classical particles.  The partition function depends on the energy and if the energy of your individual quantum states is quantized, this is where you're gonna get $\hbar$.  In this case there is a (classical) statistical uncertainty that comes from reducing the system to averages as you do in classical stat. mech, plus a fundamentally quantum uncertainty: both are "mixed" together.